# Spring Boot @PreAuthorize at class level

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot controller. My controller is derived from a base class. If I annotate a method in the base class or the base class itself with:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('BACKOFFICE')")
public ResponseEntity<?> page(@RequestBody ObjectNode json, Pageable pageable,  Authentication authentication) throws ApplicationException{
   ...
}
```

```java
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('BACKOFFICE')")
public abstract class TableController {
   ...
}
```

it works and roles are checked. I need to annotate the derived class but there `@PreAuthorized` annotation is ignored.

```java
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('BACKOFFICE')")
public class UtentiController extends TableController{
  ...
}
```

Is there a different annotation or a cofinguration required?

My security configuration is

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailServiceImpl userService;
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/css/**",  "/libs/**","/js/**", "/api/**", "/assets/**", "/register", "/public/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried with your version and still works for me. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I find annotating the TableController base class as a RestController a little suspect by the way, that would imply the abstract class should be a Spring component. Your derived class is one. Probably won't change anything, just the one odd thing in what otherwise looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Gimby you're right there's no need to annotate TableController wirh RestController because I annotated the derived class,  but even if I remove that annotation PreAuthorize is ignored on the derived class